# How to send trace to Elastic APM Server with OpenTelemetry Collector over OTLP

Tags: haproxy, elastic-apm, open-telemetry-collector

OpenTelemetry Collector Version: 0.82.0

Elastic APM Server Version: 7.12.1

HAProxy Version: 2.0.31-0ubuntu0.2

APM Server's service port is 8080 and it's in insecure mode.
I have a HAProxy LB configured in front of more than one APM Server.

Strangely, when I set exporters.otlp.endpoint to the APM Server instance IP, traces are collected normally, but when I set it to the HAProxy's IP, I get an *error.

- error

```
Sep 05 14:17:00 OTELCOL-SERVER-001 otelcol[28084]: 2023-09-05T14:17:00.601+0900        error        exporterhelper/queued_retry.go:391        Exporting failed. The error is not retryable. Dropping data.        {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "traces", "name": "otlphttp", "error": "Permanent error: error exporting items, request to http://haproxy-apm-lb:8080/v1/traces responded with HTTP Status Code 404", "dropped_items": 8}
Sep 05 14:17:00 OTELCOL-SERVER-001 otelcol[28084]: go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/exporterhelper.(*retrySender).send
Sep 05 14:17:00 OTELCOL-SERVER-001 otelcol[28084]:         go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter@v0.82.0/exporterhelper/queued_retry.go:391
Sep 05 14:17:00 OTELCOL-SERVER-001 otelcol[28084]: go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/exporterhelper.(*tracesExporterWithObservability).send
Sep 05 14:17:00 OTELCOL-SERVER-001 otelcol[28084]:         go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter@v0.82.0/exporterhelper/traces.go:126
Sep 05 14:17:00 OTELCOL-SERVER-001 otelcol[28084]: go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/exporterhelper.(*queuedRetrySender).start.func1
Sep 05 14:17:00 OTELCOL-SERVER-001 otelcol[28084]:         go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter@v0.82.0/exporterhelper/queued_retry.go:195
Sep 05 14:17:00 OTELCOL-SERVER-001 otelcol[28084]: go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/exporterhelper/internal.(*boundedMemoryQueue).StartConsumers.func1
Sep 05 14:17:00 OTELCOL-SERVER-001 otelcol[28084]:         go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter@v0.82.0/exporterhelper/internal/bounded_memory_queue.go:47
```

- Configuration

[OTELCOL-SERVER-001]

```yaml
# /etc/otelcol/config.yaml - not working, something wrong
...
exporters:
  otlphttp:
    endpoint: "http://haproxy-apm-lb:8080"
    tls:
      insecure: true
    headers:
      Content-Type: "application/json"

  logging:
    verbosity: detailed

service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [logging,otlphttp]   
...
```

```yaml
# /etc/otelcol/config.yaml - working properly
...
exporters:
  otlp:
    endpoint: "http://elastic-apm-server-001:8080"
    tls:
      insecure: true
    headers:
      Content-Type: "application/json"

  logging:
    verbosity: detailed

service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [logging,otlp]   
...
```

```bash
# /etc/otelcol/otelcol.conf
OTELCOL_OPTIONS="--config=/etc/otelcol/config.yaml"
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_HEADERS="Content-Type=application/json"
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_PROTOCOL="http/json"
```

[HAPROXY-APM-LB]

```bash
# /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
...
frontend http-in
        bind *:8080
        default_backend http_main

        acl acl_main path_beg /v1

        http-response set-header Content-Type application/json if acl_main
        use_backend http_main if acl_main

backend http_main
        mode http
        option httpchk GET /
        http-request add-header Content-Type application/json
        http-check expect status 200
        server elastic-apm-server-001         10.10.10.11:8080 check port 8080
        server elastic-apm-server-002         10.10.10.12:8080 check port 8080
...
```

I think it's because the header changes as the exporter's request goes through HAProxy.

So I tried setting the Content-Type via the set-header and add-header setting in the HAProxy frontend and backend configuration, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```yaml
# /etc/otelcol/config.yaml - not working, something wrong
...
exporters:
  otlphttp:
...
```

`otlphttp` configures the [OTLP/HTTP exporter](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/blob/main/exporter/otlphttpexporter/README.md). Support for OTLP/HTTP was added to Elastic APM Server in v8.3.0 -- see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/guide/current/release-notes-8.3.html#_added_7

```yaml
# /etc/otelcol/config.yaml - working properly
...
exporters:
  otlp:
...
```

`otlp` configures the [OTLP/gRPC exporter](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/blob/main/exporter/otlpexporter/README.md).

APM Server v7.12.1 does have support for OTLP/gRPC, but not OTLP/HTTP.

Comment: Then in a different way,
In Elasticsearch v7.12.1, when sending traces via elasticsearch exporter instead of otlp exporter, can they be consolidated and shown in timeline view with other trace logs?

Comment: @EliotK although the elasticsearch exporter does support traces, they are not written to Elasticsearch in a way that is supported by Elastic APM. So no, I'm afraid not. If you are stuck on 7.12.1 and cannot upgrade, then another option may be to run a pool of opentelemetry-collectors, and have them write OTLP/gRPC to apm-server.